# How to Convert returned values to decimal and SUM MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a number of values stored as varchar, where values are stored in the string form:

`10,000,000.00`

I would like to convert this number to a double to display:

`10000000.00` AND then SUM it with the rest of the values of that format

As these fields don't have types there may be the case where inputted data is of the form:

`10000.00` and this should be accepted as well.

How would I go about converting the unstructured numbers.
I tried:

`SELECT SUM(CAST(value as DECIMAL(10,2))) FROM meta_bs
                    WHERE bs_id = 361`

In the above case:

`10000000.00` becomes `10.00`

Please assist, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use REPLACE function to remove the commas:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(REPLACE(value, ',', '') as DECIMAL(10,2)))
FROM   meta_bs
WHERE  bs_id = 361
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44d4c/1).